# How tell if only part of the data changes?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm new to ReDux, and working on a project with multiple reducers.

In the function called/referenced by the subscribe, it is called anytime any of the data in the store is changed. For example, I have a to do list and an object which stores info on the animation, basically a list of properties. If I update a to do item I don't want to re-render the animation object. If I update an animation property, I don't want to re-render the to do list.

How can I tell which data object has been changed?

Here's the code I have that subscribes to data changes in ReDux:

```
$(function() {

    var $todoPane = $('#todopane');
    var $animFormPane = $('#animation_form');

    //  Render objects onload.
//  renderTodos($todoPane, APP.store.getState().todos.allTodos);
//  renderAniPropForm($animFormPane, APP.store.getState().animation);

    APP.store.subscribe(function() {
        //  Did some part of the ui change? (sliders that alter the height or width of panes on the page)

        //  Did todos change?
        renderTodos($todoPane, APP.store.getState().todos.allTodos);
        //  Did animation values change?
        renderAniPropForm($animFormPane, APP.store.getState().animation);
        //  Did an object change?

        //  Did an action change?

    });
});
```

What do I put where the comments like with // Did ?? values change?

Comment: Please can I know that why did you reject this edit? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16614567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach used for detecting changes in React and Redux apps is strict equality checks.  If two variables are not `===` equal, then they are assumed to be different.  This requires that you [update your data immutably](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html).

So, as a quick example:

```
let lastTodosState, lastAnimationState;

APP.store.subscribe(function() {
    //  Did some part of the ui change? (sliders that alter the height or width of panes on the page)

    const newState = store.getState();

    if(newState.todos.allTodos !== lastTodosState.allTodos) {
        renderTodos($todoPane, newState.todos.allTodos);
    }

    if(newState.animation !== lastAnimationState) {
        renderAniPropForm($animFormPane, newState.animation);
    }

    lastTodosState = newState.todos;
    lastAnimationState = newState.animation;

    //  Did an object change?
    //  Did an action change?
});
```

If you are using React for your UI layer, the React-Redux `connect` function generates components that do this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Works like a charm.

Comment: Sure. Note that there's many libs out there that help with observing Redux store subscriptions besides the official React-Redux lib.  See the [Library Integrations](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/library-integration.md) and [Store#Store Change Subscriptions](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions) sections of my Redux addons catalog for lists of what's available.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not using React, just Redux for this application. But I'll check it out for future reference.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying.  React-Redux implements its own logic for diffing values that have been extracted from the store state, but the libs in that list implement similar approaches independent of React-Redux.

Answer (score 0):

in Redux reducing operation will update the single and only state tree available which will force an entire render of all the components under a `<Provider>` enter reselect https://github.com/reactjs/reselect top the rescue. by suing memoized selectors you can remember properties and prevent your component from re render as long as the watched state by the selectors does not change